# Flutter how to get rid of the gap between rows

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, row

I was trying to make a scene contains rows and columns, but for some reasons the row with the height 20 has gaps between other rows like the gif below
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJGsa.gif

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Container(
            child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
          Row(children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: button(150),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: button(150),
            )
          ]),
          Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(child: button(20)),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              button(100),
            ],
          )
        ])));
  }
}

Widget button(double buttonwidth) {
  return ButtonTheme(
    height: buttonwidth,
    child: FlatButton(
        color: Colors.grey[200],
        child: Text(
          '',
        ),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            side: BorderSide(
                color: Colors.black, width: 1, style: BorderStyle.solid)),
        onPressed: () {}),
  );
}
```

It doesn't affect the performance overall, but just a bit annoying.
Can anybody help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FlatButton's default padding causes this. You can add this line to avoid it

```
FlatButton(
    materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
)
```